# Downloading file from the server. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version

I ran into this kind of problem while building a website. Rather, during the creation of the implementation I need. I understand how the server can send a file to the user. The code how to do it is below.
But this method transfers the file to the browser and it opens the file itself. But I would like the application to throw the file to the user directly to the download folder (or where he chooses), so that he does not have to separately click and download the file from the browser

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
        {
            var file = fileService.GetById(id);
            string filePath = file.FileLocation;
            string fileType = Path.GetExtension(file.FileLocation);
            return File(filePath, fileType);
        }
```

Comment: A server can't directly force a download to a client in a browser. It must be the result of a user action. Otherwise, a malicious site could fill the user's disk

Answer (score 0):

Any application can not force browser to open download window if you have already selected a particular file type and enable the do not show again browser. You need to fix your browser settings and try testing in different browsers, in case of firefox under General tab you will see browsing section find your file type and choose the action always ask, but , know that this will vary from person to person since server code has nothing to do with it.